# Firebase Deep Link with custom parameter at the end

Tags: firebase, flutter, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I created a Firebase Deep Link for my Flutter app to open the app after the registration process was successful. The link looks like the following:

https://myLinkDomain.page.link/routeName/

During the registration process, a parameter must be appended to the end of the link, which I must read out in the app for successful completion.
The problem is that if I append the parameter to the end of the link, I can no longer access it. The link in this case looked like this:

https://myLinkDomain.page.link/routeName/?myCustomParam=myValue

If the parameter is given in the middle of the link, I can use it in the app. Like this:

https://myLinkDomain.page.link/routeName/?myCustomParam=myValue&apn=someStuff&isi=someStuff&ibi=someStuff&ifl=someStuff

However, the registration process requires that the parameter be added to the end of the link.

Is there a way to build the Firebase Deep Link so that the parameter can be added at the end and still be recognised in the app?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Never mind. The solution is to change the order of the url parameters:
https://myLinkDomain.page.link/routeName/?apn=someStuff&isi=someStuff&ibi=someStuff&ifl=someStuff&link=myLink?myCustomParam=myValue

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Never mind. The solution is to change the order of the url parameters: myLinkDomain.page.link/routeName/…

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

No matter when this parameter goes - at start or at the end of the line.

I had the same problem with passing some custom parameters to my app.
Here is we should start with manual url construction:
[firebase manual link construction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually)

I have no easy way to pass parameters, so I just change the **link** parameter body to put here more parameters:

> https://example.page.link/?link=https://example.com/?route%3Dprofile%26param1%3DA%26param2%3DB&apn=some&isi=some&ibi=some

- prefix: https://redecor.page.link/
- main body in link parameter (should be encoded). There is the place for all needed parameters you want to pass (route=profile&param1=A&param2=B) - all parameters should be **encoded**!
  encoded should be like this: route%3Dprofile%26param1%3DA%26param2%3DB
- other parameters (what are they means you could read here) for firebase proposes (no needs to encode):
  apn=some&isi=some&ibi=some